# How to get immutable data types to reduce the potential for race conditions w/out relying on an external lib?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

Immutable data types help to reduce the potential of race conditions in asynchronous JS code. RCs are often based on global mutable state.

While functional programming avoids such state, JS isn't a purely functional language but ships with mutable reference types like `Array` or `Map`. Copying such data structures is regularly expensive, hence reference types have a tendency to leak into the global scope.

Here is a contrived example:

```js
const delay = ms =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function pushStack(ys, x, ms) {
  await delay(ms)
  ys.push(x);
  return ys;
};

async function popStack(ys, ms) {
  await delay(ms)
  const y = ys.pop();
  return y;
};

async function getLastStack(ys, ms) {
  await delay(ms)
  return ys.length - 1;
};

async function readStack(ys, ms) {
  await delay(ms)
  return ys[await getLastStack(ys, Math.random()*10)];
}

const xs = [1,2,3,4];

Promise.all([
  pushStack(xs, 5, Math.random()*10),
  readStack(xs, Math.random()*10),
  popStack(xs, Math.random()*10)
]).then(([a,b,c]) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(a), b, c);
});

/* may yield among others:

[1,2,3,5], 3, 4
[1,2,3,5], 5, 4
[1,2,3,4], 4, 5
[1,2,3,4], 5, 5
[1,2,3,4], 4, 4

*/
```

How can I avoid the mutable array (map/set/object) without depending on a complex external lib?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking for. Isn't the answer just "*then don't mutate the array*"? Also for your contrived example you haven't told us what exactly is broken about it or what the desired behaviour is. And would you know how to achieve the desired result if you could use a library?

Answer (score 0):

If we nest mutable reference types in a principled manner, we can attain structural sharing while facing only a limited performance/memory usage penalty.

The following example is based on a persistent array, i.e. an immutable array that preserves previous versions of itself. You can implement persistent objects/maps/sets using the same approach.

**Usage**

The persistent array offers three essential operations:

- consing (pushing in JS) an element
- unconsing (poping in JS) an element
- concatenating two arrays

All these ops have in common that they operate on the end of the array. This way existing elements don't need to be reindexed.

You create an persistent array using the `Iarray` constructor:

```
const a = [1,2,3];
const xs = Iarray(a);
```

You can immediately `pop`/`push`/`concat` the iarray without mutating the original array. `pop`/`push`/`concat` perform itself destructive updates that affect each other:

```
xs.push(4);
xs.concat([5,6]); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

If you want to isolate subsequent mutations, you need to invoke the `own`-method:

```
const ys = xs.own();
ys.pop(); // [6, [1,2,3,4,5]]
```

If all mutations are conducted the iarray must be converted into a native data type for further processing using the `unown`-method, which yields a generator:

```
Array.from(xs.unown()); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Array.from(ys.unown()); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

As soon as you `unown` an instance you cannot alter it anymore:

```
xs.push(7); // type error
xs.own().push(7); // okay
```

**Implementation**

Here are some notes wrt the implementation:

- uses a proxy to allow the familiar element access syntax `xs[0]`
- implements the iterable protocol
- relies on a trampoline to unnest nested data structures in a stack-safe manner
- isn't a bulletproof implementation but rather a proof of concept

Unfortunately, The trampoline renders the code more complicated but it is necessary.

Here is the full code and the example from above:

```js
const TAG = Symbol.toStringTag;

const Pair = (x, y) => ({
  [TAG]: "Pair",
  0: x,
  1: y,
  length: 2,

 [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
    yield x;
    yield y;
  }  
});

const Loop = f => x => {
  let o = f(x);

  while (o[TAG] !== "Base") {
    switch (o[TAG]) {
      case "Call": {
        o = o.f(o.x);
        break;
      }

      case "Rec": {
        o = f(o.x);
        break;
      }

      default: throw new TypeError("invalid constructor");
    }
  }

  return o.x;
};

const Loop2 = f => (x, y) => {
  let o = f(x, y);

  while (o[TAG] !== "Base") {
    switch (o[TAG]) {
      case "Call": {
        o = o.f(o.x, o.y);
        break;
      }

      case "Rec": {
        o = f(o.x, o.y);
        break;
      }

      default: throw new TypeError("invalid constructor");
    }
  }

  return o.x;
};

Loop.call = (f, x) => ({[TAG]: "Call", f, x});
Loop.rec = x => ({[TAG]: "Rec", x});
Loop.base = x => ({[TAG]: "Base", x});
Loop2.call = (f, x, y) => ({[TAG]: "Call", f, x, y});
Loop2.rec = (x, y) => ({[TAG]: "Rec", x, y});
Loop2.base = x => ({[TAG]: "Base", x});

const Iarray = xs => {
  const go = (prev, curr, offset) => {
    const o = {};
    let immutable = false;

    o[TAG] = "Iarray";
    o[Symbol.isConcatSpreadable] = true;
    o[Symbol.iterator] = () => o.unown();

    o.at = i => Loop(i2 => o.at_(i2)) (i);

    o.at_ = i => {
      const i2 = o.length - i;

      if (i2 <= o.curr.length) return Loop.base(o.curr[o.curr.length - i2]);

      else {
        const i3 = i2 - o.curr.length - o.offset;

        if (o.prev === xs) {
          if (o.prev.length === 0) return Loop.base(undefined);
          else if (o.prev.length < i3) return Loop.base(undefined);
          else return Loop.base(o.prev[o.prev.length - i3]);
        }

        else return Loop.call(o.prev.at_, i3);
      }
    };

    o.concat = ys => {
      if (immutable) throw new TypeError("concat op on immutable array");

      else {
        o.curr.push.apply(o.curr, ys);
        o.length += ys.length;
        return o;
      }
    };

    o.curr = curr;
    o.offset = offset;

    o.own = () => {
      immutable = true;
      return go(o, [], 0);
    }

    o.length = prev.length;

    o.pop = () => {
      if (immutable) throw new TypeError("pop op on immutable array");
      else if (o.length === 0) return Pair(undefined, o);

      else if (o.curr.length === 0) {
        o.length--;
        o.offset--;

        const x = o.prev === xs
          ? xs[xs.length - 1 + o.offset]
          : Loop(() => o.prev.at_(o.length - 1 + o.offset)) ();

        return Pair(x, o);
      }

      else {
        o.length--;
        return Pair(o.curr.pop(), o);
      }
    };

    o.prev = prev;

    o.push = x => {
      if (immutable) throw new TypeError("push op on immutable array");

      else {
        o.curr.push(x);
        o.length++;
        return o;
      }
    };

    o.unown = (xss = [], offset = 0) =>
      Loop2((xss2, offset2) => o.unown_(xss2, offset2)) (xss, offset);

    o.unown_ = (xss, offset) => {
      if (o.curr.length === 0) {}

      else if (offset < 0) {
        if (o.curr.length + offset < 0) offset += o.curr.length;
        
        else if (o.curr.length + offset > 0) {
          xss.push(o.curr.slice(0, offset));
          offset = 0;
        }

        else offset = 0;
      }

      else xss.push(o.curr);

      if (o.prev === xs) {
        const offset2 = offset + o.offset

        if (xs.length === 0) {}

        else if (offset2 < 0) {
          if (xs.length + offset2 < 0)
            throw TypeError("invalid persistent array offset");
          
          else if (xs.length + offset2 > 0)
            xss.push(xs.slice(0, offset2));

          else {}
        }

        else xss.push(xs);

        return Loop2.base(function* () {
          for (let i = xss.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (let x of xss[i]) yield x;
          }
        } ());
      }

      else return Loop2.call(o.prev.unown_, xss, offset + o.offset);
    };

    return new Proxy(o, {
      deleteProperty(_, i) {
        throw new TypeError(`delete op on persistent array`);
      },

      get(_, i, proxy) {
        if (typeof i === "symbol") return o[i];
        else if (String(Number(i)) === i) return Loop(i2 => o.at_(Number(i2))) (i);
        else return o[i];
      },

      has(_, i, proxy) {
        if (typeof i === "symbol") return i in o;
        else if (String(Number(i)) === i) return Number(i) < o.length;
        else return i in o;
      },

      set(_, i, v, proxy) {
        throw new TypeError(`set op on persistent array`);
      }
    });
  };

  return go(xs, [], 0);
};

const delay = ms =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function pushStack(ys, x, ms) {
  await delay(ms)
  ys.push(x);
  return ys;
};

async function popStack(ys, ms) {
  await delay(ms)
  const y = ys.pop();
  return y;
};

async function getLastStack(ys, ms) {
  await delay(ms)
  return ys.length - 1;
};

async function readStack(ys, ms) {
  await delay(ms)
  return ys[await getLastStack(ys, Math.random()*10)];
}

const xs = Iarray([1,2,3,4]);

Promise.all([
  pushStack(xs.own(), 5, Math.random()*10).then(xs => xs.unown()),
  readStack(xs, Math.random()*10),
  popStack(xs.own(), Math.random()*10)
]).then(([a,b,c]) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(
    Array.from(a)), b, c[0]); // always [1,2,3,4,5] 4 2
});
```

[A `Imap`/`Iset`/`Iobject` implementation can be found here](https://github.com/kongware/scriptum/blob/master/scriptum.js#L4119)